# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I am trying to install the opencv python library. This is the command I ran:

```
pip install python-opencv
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-opencv
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-opencv
```

I got a suggestion from a video to use this:

```
pip install python-opencv-headless
```

But still i was getting the same error.
I am using python 3.7.9. How can i fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:-

```
pip install opencv-python
```